# How do I make the F# compiler infer my arguments to the generic function?

Tags: generics, f#

I have written some test code to wrap my head around the syntax of generics:

```
let add_stuff<'T> x y =
   printfn "%A" (x + y)

let stuff() = 
    add_stuff 5.5 2.4
    add_stuff 3 4
```

The 2nd `add_stuff` call does not compile.  Why is this?  Why doesn't the compiler infer the types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 issues with the code:

First, the generic type `'T` is not used by any of the parameters. The parameters need to be declared of type `'T` like this:

```
// val add_stuff: 'T -> 'T -> unit
let add_stuff<'T> (x:'T) (y:'T) =
    printfn "%A" (x + y)
```

This creates a new error message:

> The declared type parameter 'T' cannot be used here since the type
>   parameter cannot be resolved at compile time

The issue in this case is the `+` operator. It uses Statically Resolved Type Parameters which means your function also needs to use them which basically means it needs to be inlined:

```
// val add_stuff: ^T -> ^T -> unit
let inline add_stuff (x:^T) (y:^T) =
    printfn "%A" (x + y)
```

Notice the difference in the type signature `'T` is a generic type, it can be resolved at runtime. `^T` is an SRTP, it needs to be resolved at compile time, thus the `inline` keyword.

If you had not used the `+` operator then you would not need to inline it. Notice the difference between `pair_stuff` and `add_stuff`:

```
// val pair_stuff: 'T -> 'W -> unit
let pair_stuff (x:'T) (y:'W) =
    printfn "%A" (x , y)

// val add_stuff:  ^a -> ^b -> unit
let inline add_stuff x y =
    printfn "%A" (x + y)

let stuff() = 
    add_stuff 5.5 2.4
    add_stuff 3 4
    pair_stuff 5.5 2.4
    pair_stuff 3 4

stuff()
// 7.9
// 7
// (5.5, 2.4)
// (3, 4)
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use Generics for this because they are resolved at runtime and will not vary by inlining.

You need to use [Statically Resolved Type Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters) which will be resolved at compile time:

```
let inline add_stuff (x: ^X) (y: ^Y) =
    printfn "%A" (x + y)
```

> Statically resolved type parameters are primarily useful in conjunction with member constraints, which are constraints that allow you to specify that a type argument must have a particular member or members in order to be used. There is no way to create this kind of constraint by using a regular generic type parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  It was very difficult to choose between all the answers but I chose AMieres answer just purely on the further explanation.